# How to prevent a div to collapse when we click the checkbox inside that div?

Tags: jquery

I have a checkbox present inside a div. When the user clicks on the div(except the checkbox) another div is showing and hiding. This is achieved by JQuery. But my problem is when i click on the check box the div also showing the sliding effect(which i dont want). How to prevent the div from sliding when I click on the checkbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After struggling for a day finally i got the solution. I just add a argument to the event in JQuery. Then check if the event source is of "CheckBox" type then don't collapse the div, else collapse the div. My code is as follow:

```
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
       //The event handler for the click event of the div.
        $('.divClientList').click(function(e)
        {
            //Check if the event source is other then checkbox,
            //then collapse the div, else do nothing.
            if (e.target.type != "checkbox")
            {
                //If the target div content is empty then do nothing.                    
                if ($('.divContent').is(':empty'))
                {
                }
                else
                {
                    $('.divContent').slideToggle('slow');
                }
            }

        });
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`.stopPropagation()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/) method on the checkbox. If your checkbox has the ID `thecheckbox`, use

```
$("#thecheckbox").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();
});
```